# PHP RegisterXPathNamespace - XML Prefix of Unknown Origin

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm pretty new to PHP/XPath here.  I'm using SimpleXML and XPath in PHP, traversing XML with namespaces.

My question is concerning the 'prefix' parameter in the  registerXPathNamespace function.
I have two xmlns in my xml feed; however, I'm uncertain as to how to use the function in this case.
When I run this code, I get the following error msg:

```
Undefined offset: 0
```

My XML cannot be changed in any way.
Please see the code, below.  Thanks for any leads.

PHP code:

```
<?php
$url = 'test.xml';

$simplexml = simplexml_load_file($url);
//below, I'm uncertain as to what should be the prefix, 
//in the case of no apparent prefix in the xml - I've seen 'a' in other      
//examples (where the prefix does not exist in the xml), but unsure why.
$simplexml->registerXPathNamespace('a','http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data');//
//below, as the 'dmd' prefix is in the xml, I've included it here.
$simplexml->registerXPathNamespace('dmd','http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata');
//

$myDataObjects2 = $simplexml->xpath('//Record/INTELLCONT[@id="14"]/CONTYPE')[0];
//$myDataObjects2 = $simplexml->xpath('//Record/INTELLCONT/CONTYPE')[0];
echo $myDataObjects2;
?>
```

The XML:

```
<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2018-01-03">
    <Record userId="148" username="john-doe" termId="44" dmd:surveyId="12">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="DEPARTMENT" entryKey="Toocas-CK" text="Toocas-CK"/>
        <INTELLCONT id="14" dmd:originalSource="MANUAL" dmd:lastModified="2017-02-21T15:21:45" dmd:startDate="2016-05-01" dmd:endDate="2016-07-31">
            <CONTYPE>Author Content</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER/>
            <NEWREV>Revised</NEWREV>
            <STATUS>Accepted</STATUS>
        </INTELLCONT>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have registered namespace

```
$simplexml->registerXPathNamespace('a','http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data');
```

and you need to say xpath that nodes, you are looking up, belong to that namespace

```
//a:Record/a:INTELLCONT[@id="14"]/a:CONTYPE
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/932819)

Comment: Thanks - however, my XML cannot be edited.  How can I register xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data"  with what exists in the xml document?    Thanks

Comment: This solution answers your question in registering namespace. Did you try it?

Answer (score 3):

What you have is whats called a default namespace - `xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data"` and as a default it doesn't have a prefix in your XML - it's just assumed to be there.

But in your code, you need to give it a name, so in your case you've given it a prefix of 'a'...

```
$simplexml->registerXPathNamespace('a','http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data');
```

So in your XPath, where the element in the original document does not have a prefix - it's using the default namespace, and in your code you have said that this should have a prefix of 'a'.  So your XPath should be...

```
$myDataObjects2 = $simplexml->xpath('//a:Record/a:INTELLCONT[@id="14"]/a:CONTYPE')[0];
```